# Javascript pure switch beetween 2 different CSS styles of an element

Tags: javascript, css

I've got two body styles. There are 3 ways I can imagine how to select and apply

- `applyStyle(bodyName or Element, #styleNumber)`
- `If () {select style)`
- `switch { case 1: ... case 2: ... }`

Should I store the styles in a variable or two different CSS files?

```
/* body style 1 */
body {
  background-color: #E6F6F6;
}

/* body style 2 */
body {
  background-color: #F6F6F6;
}
```

Comment: Have two separate classes, and switch between those classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using JQuery, I would do this:

```
body {
    background-color: #E6F6F6;
}
body.different {
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
}
```

Then use `$('body').toggleClass('different')` to toggle between them. [Documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Comment: Without jQuery: `document.body.classList.toggle('different')`

Answer (score 1):

You can make different classes and apply it then.

### CSS

```
 body.style1 {
       background : red;
 } 

 body.style2 {
       background : blue;
 }
```

### Javascript

```
 document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].className = 'style2';
```

Done!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the best solution (use classes instead) but what you're asking for, *CSS manipulation* with *vanilla JavaScript*, is entirely possible.

First, reference the `<style>` we will be modifying, e.g.

```
var style = document.querySelector('style');
```

Now you can access the [*CSSStyleSheet*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet) of this `<style>`

```
var sheet = style.sheet;
```

A *CSSStyleSheet* has the methods *insertRule* and *deleteRule* which work with indicies indicating where the rule of interest should be.

Now, putting this together

```
// initial
var idx = sheet.cssRules.length; // append a new rule to the end
sheet.insertRule('body {background-color: #E6F6F6;}', idx);

// then change
sheet.insertRule('body {background-color: #F6F6F6;}', idx);
sheet.removeRule(idx + 1); // remove the previous rule which got incremented one index
```

---

Another way to access *CSSStyleSheets* is through `document.styleSheets`. This skips the `<style>` step but I don't prefer it as e.g. you could end up with a *SecurityError* if you try to access a different origin hosted sheet. Going via the `<style>`, in my opinion, gives you a lot more control.